# Change alignment and colour of quote in Moderncv

Tags: moderncv

I'm using `ModernCV` to create my resume with the `casual` style : [example](http://ctan.unsw.edu.au/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv/examples/template_casual_orange.pdf). I wanted to change the alignment (to the left) and colour (to dark grey) of the quote section (where I intend to write a few lines about myself).

I'm using Texmaker as the editor.  I'm new to Latex, so somehow I can't get the right syntax to make this change. Also, should I change the .tex or the moderncvstylecasual.sty file? Appreciate any help.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. You shouldn't edit the sty-file, that could be problematic with updates.

Comment: alright, cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change all this from inside the argument to the `\quote` command. For more complicated stuff (for example if you need to change the width of the quote block), the `moderncv` class does offer some customization variables, but it lacks some proper documentation.

For even more complicated stuff, like for example if you want the quote to appear above your name (why would you want to do that, but that's an example), you might need to modify the `\makecvtitle` command. However, this should always be done in your document, using `\renewcommand`. In most cases, editting the source code of a package isn't needed, and should be avoided.

```
\documentclass{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{casual}

\definecolor{dark-gray}{gray}{0.20}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}
\quote{{\raggedright\color{dark-gray}\lipsum[1]}} % Replace "\lipsum[1]" with your quote

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\end{document}
```

[image]